# Diagonal lines for brush stroke or dashed stroke

Tags: adobe-illustrator, stroke, brush

I would like to stroke a path with 45 degree diagonal lines that are set a fixed distance of of 0.125 inches to each other.

I'd also like the diagonals not to distort on curves- in other words, I want the diagonals to remain straight line segments that are parallel to the tangent of a curve at a any point.

I hope this is clear.

Is this possible?

Update:

This is for laser cutting a pattern - Adam's solution works nicely.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[image: Slashed Stroke]

Something like this?

I kinda hacked it, so hopefully someone has a proper way to do this.

What I did here was use the `text` tool over the path, and fill it with pipes `|` (`Shift` + `\`)(above the `return` key).

Next I changed the `tracking`, `baseline`, and `text rotation` in the `Character` window to get the lines spaced and angled properly.

Hopefully this is what you're looking for. If not, hope it steers you in the right direction!

Comment: This may be a hack, but it solves my problem exactly. Thank you very much! I regret I don't have enough reputation to upvote your common-sense and direct answer.

Comment: Perhaps you could also create a new shape in the shapes palette (exactly the angle you need) and apply that shape over the path

Comment: I'll try that, Krom.

Comment: Just checked with CS2 - "Scatter Brush" does not distort around curves and can align to a path. So if you need more control over the elements - create a "Scatter Brush" and apply it.

Comment: I recently found this tutorial. Leaving it here for reference. http://y-designs.com/support/tutorials/illustrator-tutorial-wrapping-a-pattern-around-a-circular-path.html#.VPSEOLPF-7A

Answer (score -1):

You could simply use a dashed stroke....

[image: hashes]

Unless you actually mean you want all the hashes at 45° at all times. In that case, the closest you'll get is a pattern brush after some effort. And brushes distort around curves. So, I don't know what you'd do in those situations.

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: I put a downvote on this answer because its focused on answering a different question. OP specifically needs 45 degree slated lines. Now I thought that your attempt and motivation was good, but the actual answer that I voted for was a bad one - it **did not** answered the question. So in my opinion this could be a comment at most, asking OP "are you sure dashed strokes dont suit you?"